# How does one implement a delegated authorisation model with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization

So, I have a PHP website with user credentials (username & password) and I would like to develop another website in Rails and would like to implement a delegated authorisation model; I would like the user to be able to login to the rails website and be able to login in using the credentials from the PHP website. It is similar to the model where one can login to another site with their Google account. I have read the following: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/79776, I am not quite sure which model (see the link provided in the answer) suits me. How would I go about implementing this model in rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://auth0.com/learn/how-to-implement-single-sign-on/

I have realised that SSO (Single-Sign-On) implementation can be carried out by using products like auth 0; they require that the backends on both sites (the PHP and rails one) need configuration so as to allow the auth0 SSO products to work; I have left a link for implementation with Rails and SSO:

https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/rails/00-introduction

Note: This stuff is pretty difficult and can take a long time to implement.